# How to get particular value form javascript associative array

Tags: javascript, syntax, get, return-value, associative-array

HI i have a matrix aray like below

```
var pricemultiarray = {
    "Coast-to-Coast": {
        "1": ["10", "20", "30", "50", "60"],
            "2": ["15", "30", "40", "60", "80"],
            "3": ["20", "40", "50", "70", "100"],
            "4": ["20", "40", "50", "70", "100"],
            "5": ["20", "45", "60", "95", "115"],
            "6": ["20", "45", "60", "95", "115"],
            "7": ["25", "55", "75", "105", "125"]
    },

        "mid-states": {
        "1": ["10", "20", "30", "45", "55"],
            "2": ["15", "30", "40", "45", "70"],
            "3": ["20", "40", "50", "60", "95"],
            "4": ["20", "40", "50", "60", "95"],
            "5": ["20", "45", "60", "90", "110"],
            "6": ["20", "45", "60", "90", "110"],
            "7": ["25", "55", "75", "105", "125"]
    },


        "In-State": {
        "1": ["10", "15", "20", "45", "50"],
            "2": ["10", "20", "25", "50", "60"],
            "3": ["10", "25", "35", "70", "80"],
            "4": ["10", "25", "35", "70", "80"],
            "5": ["10", "25", "30", "85", "95"],
            "6": ["10", "25", "30", "85", "95"],
            "7": ["25", "55", "75", "105", "125"]
    }


};
```

in this i need to get a particular value from the array like

> 1 Coast-to-Coast -> 1 -> 3

so what will b the syntax of getting the above value form the array. Please suggest

Comment: It is a good question - I am really sorry for the -1, but I think you need some motivation to repair your writing quality.

Comment: `1 Coast-to-Coast -> 1 -> 3` what do you mean by ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`pricemultiarray["Coast-to-Coast"]["1"]` will return `["10","20","30","50","60"]` and
`pricemultiarray["Coast-to-Coast"]["1"][0]` will return `"10"`

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
for ( var i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
alert(pricemultiarray["Coast-to-Coast"][i]);
//console.log(pricemultiarray["Coast-to-Coast"][i]);
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhW3m/)

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks guts for al of  your help  i use the below code

> var coast =  (document.getElementById("coast").value); var boxsize = 
>   (document.getElementById("boxsize").value); var day = 
>   (document.getElementById("day").value);
>   alert(pricemultiarray[coast][boxsize][day]);

and it works fine now for me

thanks a lot